# Application only seeing half the threads available on dual-processor machine

Tags: linux, windows, multithreading, cpu-architecture, processor

We recently acquired a dual-processor Dell workstation, equipped with two Xeon 6138 Gold CPUs. Each CPU has 20 physical cores (40 logical cores), so there is a total of 40 physical cores or 80 logical cores.

Both Linux Fedora and Windows 10 Professional are installed on this machine using a dual-boot setup. Note that I have not installed this machine myself.

The Windows task manager correctly displays 80 logical cores. These 80 cores are also available on Linux when looking under /proc.

When running PBRT (https://www.pbrt.org/) on Linux, the application correctly uses (and saturates) 80 cores.

On Windows, however, the process only uses 40 logical cores out of 80. I haven't checked, but I am pretty sure that PBRT uses std::thread::hardware_concurrency(),
which is a good way to determine the number of cores. If I force PBRT to use 80 threads thanks to a command line option, the Windows task manager does not show that all cores are saturated. Only half of them are. It seems a single Windows process cannot use all 80 logical cores to me.

Is this a limitation of Windows? This is surprising.

Am I supposed to install a specific version of Windows to make sure all cores are available to a single process?

Comment: Is that 40 logical cores on one CPU, or 40 physical cores on two CPUs? Are you able to use all 80 somehow, e.g. by running two instances, or by using a thread testing tool?

Comment: Does Windows have some kind of license restriction that makes it artificially limit you?

Comment: there are 40 logical cores per CPU. Yes, I am able to use all 80 logical cores if I run two PBRT processes concurrently. I can see that in the task manager.

Comment: @PeterCordes not that I know of. I confirm PBRT uses std::thread::hardware_concurrency() as I see in the code. The function probably returns 40 (not 80) on Windows.

Comment: That does make some sense.  Depending on the workload (and cache footprint per thread), running 1 thread per physical core can be better than 1 thread per logical core.  But if the OS's scheduler does a terrible job of keeping all the physical cores busy, then it's a problem.  Also, some workloads do benefit from running multiple threads per physical core to hide branch misses, instruction latency, and so on.  (even some high instruction-throughput code like x265 video encoding gets a small speedup from Hyperthreading on Skylake, like ~15% last I tested.)